# Converting a CGAffineTransform to a GLKMatrix3

Tags: ios, c, opengl-es, avfoundation, core-video

I'm trying to render a video to a texture surface but I'm having a few problems with texture coordinates.

I'm using CoreVideo to grab the texture surface using an CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage call.  This part is working fine.  Now I want to rotate the video so it appears at the correct orientation.  It struck me that one way to do this would be via a texture coordinate matrix.  To that end I grab the preferredTransform and naturalSize from my AVAssetTrack.

Now I start to get problems.  The preferredTransform contains a translation (tx, ty) in pixels but I need this "normalised" so I do the following to get my matrix:

```
    CGSize transSize    = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform( videoSize, videoTransform );
    videoTransform.tx   /= -transSize.width;
    videoTransform.ty   /= -transSize.height;
```

(Note I'm not sure why I need to negate the transformed size but if I don't then things will not end up in the 0->1 range).

I then form a GLKMatrix3 as follows:

```
GLKMatrix3 CGAffineTransformToGLKMatrix3( CGAffineTransform affineTransform )
{
    return GLKMatrix3Make(  affineTransform.a,  affineTransform.b,  0,
                            affineTransform.c,  affineTransform.d,  0,
                            affineTransform.tx, affineTransform.ty, 1 );
}
```

This does appear to transform everything nearly perfectly.  However while videos shot in landscape appear perfectly, videos that are shot in portrait appear upside down.

So obviously I'm doing something wrong but I've spent a fair bit of time on this and got nowhere.  Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know which way the landscape video was rotated -90 or 90 in order to invert that transform for display

3x3 affine matrix

```
xx    xy    x0
yx    yy    y0
0     0     1
```

not sure how a,b,c,d,tx,ty map but expect apple's docs may help

Here's an example of an affine with angle a
// rotate, counter clockwise, a radians

```
cos(a)   -sin(a)    0
sin(a)    cos(a)    0
0         0         1
```

Comment: not sure this will help but if preferredTransform a & d == -1.0 it'll specify which way to rotate I think, not 100% sure on which element is which